# Why can't I update my Pi?

Tags: rpi-update

Whenever I try the command `sudo apt-get update` it outputs this error:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
```

`N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?`

I couldn't find any answers online.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because somewhere on the way you must have configured an APT repository pointing to an HTTPS URL (check the files at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`).

Per the error message to fix the problem you need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

and most likely also:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Comment: I've already tried the first of those two, and the "package not found" error occured.

Comment: Well, reading your question again and again, I can't see any mention you "have already tried". Until you ask a proper question, you won't get an answer that solves your problem. And it looks like you have messed your APT sources completely.

Comment: Well, I didn't ever delete or mess with any apt source files, so I don't see how this could have happened, unless I have a virus or something.

Comment: Start again with a fresh image. There's nothing else anyone without clairvoyant powers can advice you.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it again from another window, and the install worked!

Answer (score 1):

I have checked `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. In my case there I found two files. raspi.list and influxdb.list.  I found https in influxdb.list file. I removed influxdb.list file with `rm` command. Now my Raspberrypi works perfectly. I am able to run `sudo apt-get update` without any errors.